# Find all files, create CSV with one row per subdirectory and file names in collumns

Tags: command-line, files, csv

I have a directory with subdirectories and files structured like this:

```
01/fileA
01/fileB
01/fileC
02/fileD
02/fileE
03/fileF
03/fileG
03/fileH
04/fileI
```

I'd like to get a CSV that looks like this:

```
01, fileA, fileB, fileC
02, fileD, fileE
03, fileF, fileG, fileH
04, fileI
```

In other words, I want to generate a CSV with one row per subdirectory, with files listed as columns.

Is it possible to do this from the Linux command line?

Comment: When you say Bash, you mean bash and only bash? No sed, awk, find or other standard utils?

Comment: Any standard utils are okay, just edited question to clarify.

Comment: FYI, standard CSVs should not have a space *and* a comma as a delimiter—just a comma.  It's less human readable, but more computer friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done in a number of ways.  One simple method could be this

```
for d in *
do  echo -n "$d, "
    ls -m $d
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. But, I'm getting a line feed before the last file sometimes.

`01, fileA, fileB, fileC [LF]
02, fileD [LF]
fileE [LF]
03, FileF [LF]`

and so on. There are no commas in file name either.

Comment: That sounds strange.  It looks as if the `ls` for directory `02` was run without `-m`.  Do you have an actual example?  A file tree that causes this?

Comment: Use `ls -w0 -m "$d"` to avoid hitting the default line length too early

Comment: Ah, good point!

Comment: In my version OS `ls -w0` caused an error, but I was able to use `ls -w99999999`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably overkill, but using GNU datamash

```
find 0? -type f | sort -t/ | datamash -t\/ groupby 1 collapse 2 | sed 's/\//,/'
01,fileA,fileB,fileC
02,fileD,fileE
03,fileF,fileG,fileH
04,fileI
```

Or with a perl [hash of arrays](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch09_02.htm)

```
find 0? -type f | perl -F/ -alne '
  push @{$dirs{$F[0]}}, $F[1]; 
  END{
    for $d (sort keys %dirs) {print join ",", $d, sort @{$dirs{$d}}}
  }'
01,fileA,fileB,fileC
02,fileD,fileE
03,fileF,fileG,fileH
04,fileI
```

or with GNU awk

```
find 0? -type f | sort -t/ | gawk -F/ '
  {dirs[$1] = dirs[$1] "," $2} 
  END {
    n = asorti(dirs,sdirs); 
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print sdirs[i] "" dirs[sdirs[i]]
}'
01,fileA,fileB,fileC
02,fileD,fileE
03,fileF,fileG,fileH
04,fileI
```

With GNU awk > 4.0 you can simplify the array traversal to

```
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
    for (d in dirs) print d "" dirs[d];
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
find * -type d -printf "\n%p, " -exec ls -w0 -m {} \; |
    sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/, *$//'
```

Output

```
01, fileA, fileB, fileC
02, fileD, fileE
03, fileF, fileG, fileH
04, fileI
```